# List of features supported by the Lync SDK in UISuppressionMode

Tags: c#, wpf, lync

I'm currently developing a custom Lync client. I need full control over the UI.
If possible could anyone provide a list of all the supported features of Lync client's SuppressionMode API?

i.e. Desktop sharing? File Transfer? Docking of the VideoChannel? Instance messaging? etc..

**-- Edit: New info**

As it says here in the link below:

> With these lower-level API’s we can implement our own client but it has now become a much larger task. Things that were for free, are now very big implementations we must develop ourselves rather than customize:

Does this mean that there is a way to use\access these advanced API features, and what's left is the development of the custom user controls?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any definitive list of supported features, but I can comment based on work i've done in the past:

Supported in UI Suppression mode:

- IM
- Presence
- Audio (to Lync and PSTN)
- Video (A video window can be docked into your WPF/WinForms app)
- Contact Management
- Accessing A/V devices
- Setting Note
- Conferencing (IM/AV)
- Context Channel

NOT supported in UI Suppression mode:

- Sharing (Desktop/Application/Powerpoint/Whiteboard/Poll/File)

I'm sure there are other features I've left out - if theres anything specific you're interested in, leave a comment and i'll update the answer.

I don't really understand the second part of your question i'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you, I believe the question was answered. The second part revolved around the Sharing capabilities which you covered already in your answer. :)

Comment: Microsoft release an update with Application Sharing Supported in UI Supression mode,
you can find the update here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824, and find example here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Lync-Client-2013-SDK-CU2-02f9292e.

please update your answer